# Spring Data JPA retrieve a property that is a list

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an Entity "Request" with a @OneToMany relationship with the "LogItem" Entity. The LogItem does not have a "request" property(so, I cannot retrive them with "findAllByRequest" in a `CrudRepository<LogItem, Long>`).

I want to retrieve all of the logItems of a given request. Something like `List<LogItem> findLogItemsByRequestId(Long)`.

Of course, I see two possibilities:

- Just retrieve with fetch the entire "Request" entity. But maybe it has some other relationships and I do not want to do all those selects when there is no need for them.
- Do a custom query. But I have to do the query myself.

There is any way to do that by defining an specific method at the Request repository?

UPDATE: I have been able to retrieve the list by defining a projection that only has the "logs" property and searching for it. Still, I would like to find a way to do it directly.

Answer (score 0):

##### If you do not keep `Request` property on `LogItem` entity, unfortunately, there is no way you can fetch it from the `LogItem` side.

The most suitable solution would be to use a bi-directional relation by adding a `Request` property. If it becomes a necessity in your system to get `LogItem` entities based on their `Request` property, it is a good sign of the fact that you will need it more in the future.

If adding `Request` property is not an option, only way to fetch LogItem entities based on Request id would be to do it from Request side. By using a custom query on your repo level would work, no additional projection is needed.

You can just add the following method to your **Request repository**.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT req.logItems FROM Request req WHERE req.id = :requestId")
List<LogItem> findLogItemsByRequestId(Long requestId);
```

In order to make an improvement based on your desired solution, you can make a little trick and put that method on your **LogItem repository**.